# How to get everything after and before on a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have similar entries in my database:

```
Col1
---------
test\abcd\123\
test\abc\
test\abc\12\
test\abcdefg\1234\
```

I want to trim the string so I get: `abcd` or `abc` (middle part between the two backslashes)

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work (cuts too much)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('\',col1) + 1, CHARINDEX('\',col1,CHARINDEX('\',col1)) + 1)
```

I just need the middle part between the two backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the string between the first and the second backslashes as

```
with t(col1) as
(
 select 'test\abc\123\'      union all
 select 'test\abc\'          union all
 select 'test\abc\12\'       union all    
 select 'test\abcdefg\1234\'     
) 
select SUBSTRING(
         col1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1,CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1)-
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)-1
         )
  from t;

Result String
-------------
abc
abc
abc
abcdefg
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/PDK52495)</kbd>

**Edit** (against probability of having col1 values with less than two backslashes use)**:**

```
select SUBSTRING(
         col1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1,CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1)-
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)-1
         )
  from t
 where len(col1) - len(replace(col1,'\','')) >= 2
```

to filter completely them away.

***or***

```
select case when len(col1) - len(replace(col1,'\','')) >= 2 then
       SUBSTRING(
         col1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1,
         CHARINDEX('\',col1,CHARINDEX('\',col1)+1)-
         CHARINDEX('\',col1)-1
         )
       else
         col1
       end
         as "Result String"           
  from t
```

display all rows, leave the ones as the same spoiling the rule.

Comment: Do I have to enter manually all my entries in the query for it to work?

Comment: @ChristopherBoisvert definitely not, think `t` as your table( replace `from t` with `from yourTable`  ), and remove the part `with t(col1) as ( ... )` for your query.

Comment: I have the following error...

  Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @ChristopherBoisvert depending on your sample data in the question, there's no problem,but it seems you have some rows with values having missing two backslashes in it.

Comment: @ChristopherBoisvert you need to filter such column values by adding `where len(col1) - len(replace(col1,'\','')) >= 2` to the query.

Comment: I noticed that my col2 (from another TBL) is affected by the substring. My col3 and col4 works since they're INT's but whenever it's a charor a varchar it gets affected